# Why code inside function runs when I create new instance of a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
function PageState(){
        let currentState = new homeState();

        this.change = function(state){
            currentState=state;
        }
    }

const page = new PageState();
```

What I want to ask you about is that why if we create new instance of a function the code inside that function runs. Just what is the reason of running the code inside of function when we create new instance of that function since I am beginner in JS

Comment: You're not creating a "new instance of the function". You're creating a new *object* that is initialized by the code in the function.

Comment: This is how `new` keyword works. It is equvialent to `PageState.call(Object.create(PageState.prototype))`. So basically you have a function call with new instance of an object, not new instance of a function.

Comment: @Pointy, sorry about that my mistake, please can you explain when we use const page = new PageState and when we use const page = new PageState(). What is the reason of running the object of the function after initialization. I rreally hope for your help

Comment: @Robert, ok Robert, you know, I still cannot get in what situation to use const page = new PageState(); (lol), ok we create instance of the object but why to run it then. Can you please give an example since you are more experienced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are  creating a new instance of the function and calling the function, by using parentheses after the function name, and then assigning the new instance of the function to the variable page.

If you omit the parentheses you will create a new instance of the function and assign it to the variable page (without calling the function).
const page = new PageState;

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, well, when would we ever call the function after initialization. I just want to understand when we use const page = new PageState and when we use const page = new PageState(). I really hope for your help

Comment: You would call the function after creating an instance if you need to call it - it depends on the needs of your application or flow. 

However it is slightly confusing to call a newly created instance of a function using this syntax. I find it clearer to create the instance and assign it to a variable and then call the instance using the variable name.

const page = new PageState;
page();

Comment: Pop if the function is immutable (nothing changing inside the function) there is no value to create a new instance of the function - unless perhaps you are inheriting it into another object or class. However if you are passing data to the function and the function is creating a new object using that data and returning that object, then there is value. For example: you could have many instances of a bicycle, each with a different color, speed, etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/…